# CSS Grid grid-areas not working as expected in react form, the grid-areas are not in the format that I have specified in the grid container

Tags: react-hooks, css-grid, react-hook-form

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-raman-fhf705)

My form inputs are not appearing as per the format I have specified in my grid-template-areas. The area names are in the correct position when you view the grid layout in DevTools, but the input narratives don't match up.

For example, the row 3 should be "email email", and although the area name shows this is true for both columns, the second column in row 3 is actually showing the text 'please enter your query...' which is the placeholder for the query grid-area.

I have attempted to replicate the issue in codesandbox and attach it (and have also attached snippets of my code). I am new to this, so apologies if this has not worked, I have tried to follow the 'runnable example' guidelines.

ContactForm.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import styles from "./ContactForm.module.css";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      query: "",
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  console.log(errors);

  return (
    <div className={styles.contactFormContainer}>
      <form className={styles.gridContainer} onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <h2 className={styles.h2}>Contact Form</h2>

        <input
          className={styles.firstName}
          type="text"
          placeholder="First name"
          {...register("firstName", { required: true, maxLength: 80 })}
        />

        <input
          className={styles.lastName}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Last name"
          {...register("lastName", { required: true, maxLength: 100 })}
        />

        <input
          className={styles.email}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email"
          {...register("email", {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i,
          })}
        />

        <input
          className={styles.query}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Please enter your query (max 500 characters):"
          {...register("query", {
            required: true,
            maxLength: 500,
          })}
        />

        <input className={styles.submit} type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

ContactForm.module.css

```js
.contactFormContainer {
    margin: 20px;
    border: solid 2px  #0B2447;
    border-radius: 5%;
    width: 400px;

}

.gridContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
    grid-template-areas: 
        "h2 h2"
        "firstName lastName"
        "email ..."
        "query query"
        "submit .";
}

.h2 {
    grid-area: h2;
    align-self: center;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #0B2447;
}


.firstName > input {
    grid-area: firstName;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.lastName > input {
    grid-area: lastName;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.email > input {
    grid-area: email;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.query > input {
    grid-area: query;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5%;
}

.submit {
    grid-area: submit;
    border-radius: 5%;
}
```

App.js

```js
import "./styles.css";
import ContactForm from "/ContactForm";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ContactForm />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Index.js

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

I have gone through many related questions on here (and Google) and have adapted my code along the way, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent hours on what I know will be a simple mistake!

Comment: I have resolved question this by removing the '> input' in the ContactForm.module.css file. I originally added this after googling how to make the input box span the whole width of the grid, and seeing this as a suggestion. I now see that this was incorrect.